# A* Pathfinding 4 directions

Tags: path-finding

I need pathfinding in a project with only 4 directions.
So I looked at the A* algorythm, and I tried to draw something to understand how it's going to work.

But I noticed that there are multiple paths that are the 'same' to get to my endpoint, my question is: How is the algorythm going to choose between all these paths that cost the same, and Isn't there a way to modify this algorythm to optimize it specifically for 4 directions and no diagonals?

Here's a little drawing of the result:
[image]

EDIT: 
basically what I think may suit my implementation, is to add a T value to each node which will represent the number of 'turns' needed from the starting node.
With this, when checking adjacent nodes, if some of them have the same F value,  move to the node with the lowest T value.

EDIT2: well it's a little trickier than that
It might work if I assign a higher value for each turn and then calculate F = G + H + T

Comment: Do you prefer a specific one of these paths?

Comment: well, It'd be better if the path was the straightest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient Path finding algorithm avoiding zigzag's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302126/efficient-path-finding-algorithm-avoiding-zigzags)

Comment: what do you assume to be "straightest" on a grid? The path with the least amount of turns or the path closest to the diagonal?

Comment: @tofro The path with the least amount of turns.

Comment: Note that if you do add a #turns, the coordinates of a node have to be extended with a direction otherwise nodes with equal (x,y) would be merged but paths that go through (x,y) in different directions are fundamentally different once you count turns.